# Configuring grails proxy

Tags: grails, groovy, ggts

after adding proxy configuration in the file `BuildConfig.groovy` with
 this command

```
grails add-proxy client --host=192.168.1.1 --port=3128)
```

i got this error:

```
Problem executing: grails add-proxy toto --host=192.168.1.1 --port=3128 
The command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javaw.exe 
was terminated because it didn't produce new output for some time.
See details for the output produced so far.

If you think the command simply needed more time, you can increase the time
limit in  the Grails preferences page.

See menu Windows >> Preferences >> Grails >> Launch
Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javaw.exe (8 déc. 2014 13:30:47)
---- System.out ----
|Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath
---- System.err ----

Terminating process: Timeout: no new output for 180000 milliseconds
------System.out:-----------
|Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath
------System.err:-----------

Terminating process: Timeout: no new output for 180000 milliseconds
```

what's wrong

Comment: do you really have put the closing `)` at the end of the port?  is the proxy working and can you in general connect (`telnet 192.168.1.1 3128` (or whatever windows uses))?  does the proxy need auth?  any errors in the proxy log?

Comment: yes the proxy work very well. no there is no closing at the end of the port. no proxy don't need auth. please can you post or tell how to create the file proxySettings.groovy ?

Comment: have you tried quoting the params?  e.g. `grails add-proxy client "--host=192.168.1.1" "--port=3128"`

Comment: Problem executing: grails add-proxy client "--host=192.168.1.1" "--port=3128"
The command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javaw.exe (9 déc. 2014 12:21:26)' was terminated because it didn't produce new output for some time.

See details for the output produced so far.

If you think the command simply needed more time, you can increase the time limit in the Grails preferences page.

See menu Windows >> Preferences >> Grails >> Launch
Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javaw.exe (9 déc. 2014 12:21:26)
---- System.out ----
|Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath